# Expected size of binomial coefficient with Poisson arrivals?

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability

I have a Poisson process where new elements arrive to a set with Poisson intensity $\lambda$. Initially, there are $N_0$ elements in the set.  The probability that there are $N_0 + M$ elements in the set at time $t$ is $Pr[N(t) = N_0+M] = \frac{(\lambda t)^M}{M!} e^{-\lambda t}$.

I'm interested in the expected number of subsets of size $k$. That is, I want to compute

$$f(k,t) = \sum_{M=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\lambda t)^M}{M!} e^{-\lambda t} \binom{N_0+M}{k}$$

Is there some formula or approximation for this expectation when $N_0$ is large?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that a real $c:=\lambda t>0$ and a natural $k$ are fixed, whereas $n:=N_0\to\infty$.
Take any real $m>0$. Then
$$f(k,t)=g_m(k,t)+h_m(k,t),$$
where
$$g_m(k,t):=e^{-c}\sum_{0\le j<m}\frac{c^j}{j!}\,\binom{n+j}k,$$
$$h_m(k,t):=e^{-c}\sum_{j\ge m}\frac{c^j}{j!}\,\binom{n+j}k.$$
For each $j$, $\binom{n+j}k\sim n^k/k!$, whence
$$g_m(k,t)\sim P_m\frac{n^k}{k!},$$
where
$$P_m:=e^{-c}\sum_{0\le j<m}\frac{c^j}{j!}.$$
Also, $\binom{n+j}k\le(n+j)^k/k!=O(n^k+j^k)$ for all $j$, whence
$$h_m(k,t)=O\Big((1-P_m)n^k+\sum_{j\ge0}\frac{c^j}{j!}\,j^k\Big)
=O\Big((1-P_m)n^k+1\Big)
=O\big((1-P_m)n^k\big).$$
Letting now $m\to\infty$ and noting that then $P_m\to1$, we conclude that
$$f(k,t)\sim\frac{n^k}{k!}.$$